# Pause and restart CSS transition on mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I would like to know how you can pause and restart a CSS transition.

Code snippet:

```js
animationstate = "running";

function animate() {
    if (animationstate == "running") {
        deskppssystemdiv.style.transitionDuration = "2000ms";
        deskppssystemdiv.style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
        deskppssystemdiv.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
    }
}
animate();

deskppssystemdiv.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    animationstate = "paused";
});

deskppssystemdiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    animationstate = "running";
});
```

I guess this can be done with `getComputedStyle` property or `addClass` and `removeClass`, but I am stuck.

Comment: So what exactly is the `transition`? Is it a change in degree of `transform: rotate(Xdeg)`? Also, what should happen if I move the mouse in after the transition is already complete?

Comment: After the transition is finished nothing should happen. The transition is the transform: rotate(Xdeg).

Comment: It would be easier to do this if it were an animation because animations have a built-in `animation-play-state` property unlike transitions. But we can't always replace a transition with an animation because animations run automatically whereas transitions happen only when there is a state change. If you could create a minimal demo with your full current code - HTML, CSS and JS then it might make it more easier for answering.

Answer (score 0):

after doing some tests the following code now works for me:

```
var starttime=0
var stoptime=0
var runtime=0
var resttime=0
function animate(duration)
{
deskppssystemdiv.style.transitionDuration=duration
deskppssystemdiv.style.transitionTimingFunction="linear"
deskppssystemdiv.style.transform="rotate(45deg)"
}
starttime=Date.now()
animate("2000ms")
deskppssystemdiv.addEventListener("mouseenter",function()
{
stoptime=Date.now()
runtime=runtime+(stoptime-starttime)
resttime=2000-runtime
deskppssystemdiv.style.transform=getComputedStyle(deskppssystemdiv).
getPropertyValue("transform")
})
deskppssystemdiv.addEventListener("mouseleave",function()
{
starttime=Date.now()
animate(resttime+"ms")
})
```

My approach was to use extra time variables.
If someone finds this helpfully, please mark as answered and / or vote.